# Adjust iOS volume using mobile terminal

Tags: ios, ipad, shell, sh, jailbreak

How can I change the system volume of an iOS device through the command line? I use `ssh` to control some of the ipad and I was wondering if there was a way to change the volume, such as media and sound effects. I know on mac, you can use `osascript`, but that is not available on the ipad, which uses `bourne` again `shell`. Maybe there is some utility that can can add `osascript` (applescript) to the `shell`?